# Templates: SFINAE specialization not getting applied

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, specialization

The below snippet is, at least I thought, as straightward an example as possible of [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) applied to specialization.

The last line is the main point, and where the failure is occurring.  The definition of a specialized `foo` template determines the specialization of the `bar` template, or so I want.  Other `bar` specializations can be defined elsewhere, or perhaps the use of arbitary types can simply remain unsupported.

The same pattern is widely suggested for use with `enable_if`, as I understand.

```
template <typename T>
struct foo;

template <>
struct foo<int> {
  using type = int;
};

template <typename T, typename use = void>
struct bar;

template <typename T>
struct bar<T, typename foo<T>::type> {
  using type = typename foo<T>::type;
};

using good = typename foo<int>::type;
using bad = typename bar<int>::type;
```

In g++, with 14 or 17 standard, the result is shown below.  It seems that the `bar` specialization is not getting applied, and the compiler is using the unspecialized (empty) definition.  Why?

```
$ g++ --std=c++14 special.cpp -o special
special.cpp:18:32: error: ‘type’ in ‘struct bar<int>’ does not name a type
 using bad = typename bar<int>::type;
```

Comment: `bar<int, foo<int>::type> <==> bar<int, int>` `bar<int, void> != bar<int, int>`

Comment: You are instantiating `bar<int, void>`. Why do you expect the compiler to use anything else but the "empty" definition? Your "non-empty" specialization of `bar` does not even remotely match `<int, void>` arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
struct bar<T, typename foo<T>::type> {
  using type = typename foo<T>::type;
};
```

should be

```
template <typename T>
struct bar<T, std::void_t<typename foo<T>::type>> {
  using type = typename foo<T>::type;
};
```

as `use` should always be `void`.

That's why naming as `AlwaysVoid` would be better.
(or use its role as something like `Enabler`)

```
template <typename T, typename AlwaysVoid = void>
struct bar;
```